# String '(LISTAGG result)' is too long and would be truncated - How to fix this?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.ID, LISTAGG(D.PROCESS_ID,',')
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B
ON A.ST_ID = B.ST_ID
JOIN table2 C
ON A.ST_ID = C.ST_ID
JOIN table4 D
ON A.ST_ID = C.ST_ID
WHERE B.DATE = '2022-02-02'
AND FL_CD NOT IN ('1','2','3','4','5')
GROUP BY 1
```

When I run the above code, I'm getting this error- String '(LISTAGG result)' is too long and would be truncated. This is because of PROCESS_ID column as it is having huge values. Kindly provide a solution to fix this.

Comment: Write your own function/stored proc to produce the result you want?

Comment: What are you expecting as the solution? If you data doesn't fit... then what to do?

Comment: Is it possible to use  overflow clause that supports the truncate option (as alternative to the default on overflow error behavior)?

Comment: What overflow clause?

Comment: Not sure about it exactly. Kindly guide me with a solution. Can I write a function or stored procedure to generate the result I want. If so, kindly guide.

Comment: You need to write a SP that queries for the data you need and loops through it adding it to a string - which you then return

Comment: turn data into arrays of strings is a code smell that you are processing your data incorrectly.

Comment: Is it possible that this isn't caused by any data issues or limitations, but rather because of a typo in your JOIN condition on table4?  `JOIN table4 D ON A.ST_ID = C.ST_ID` doesn't look right.  Is that just a typo in your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many answers are calling, there's probably an exploding join that's creating way more data than expected.

In any case, I created an UDTF in JavaScript that can receive a table and extract a limited number of sample elements for each label — which is basically what the question is asking for:

```js
create or replace function limited_array_agg(arr_limit float, g string, s string)
returns table (G string, S array)
language javascript
as $$
{
    processRow: function f(row, rowWriter, context){
        if(this.counter < row.ARR_LIMIT){
            this.arr.push(row.S)
            this.group = row.G
            this.counter++;
        };
    }        
    , initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.arr = [];
    }, finalize: function(rowWriter, context){
        rowWriter.writeRow({G:this.group, S: this.arr})
    }
}
$$;
```

You can use it like this, where your query could be a CTE:

```sql
select limited_agg.g, limited_agg.s
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf100.part
    , table(limited_array_agg(
        3::float
        , p_mfgr
        , p_name) over(partition by p_mfgr)) limited_agg
;
```

[image]

In the meantime: I wish Snowflake had a native `array_agg()` that limits the number of elements.

Comment: `In the meantime: I wish Snowflake had a native array_agg() that limits the number of elements.`  We actually have it (hidden gem of **MIN_BY/MAX_BY**) - [Snowflake - ARRAY_AGG with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506601/5070879)

Comment: And by having an array there is just a single step to string: [Snowflake - LISTAGG with LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77208016/5070879)