# Avoid "String is too long" Warning with LISTAGG in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, truncate, listagg

I have been using the LISTAGG function in Snowflake to concatenate strings and I triggered the following warning:

`100078 (22000): String '(LISTAGG result)' is too long and would be truncated`

I understand that this warning is triggered when the aggregated string exceeds a certain length. I want to know the best practices to prevent or handle this warning, given that truncation is fine and not relevant for the quality of column. Should I truncate in advance the result? If so, how?

```
SELECT
        userid,
        NULLIF(LISTAGG(DISTINCT city, ', '), '') AS cities,
        NULLIF(LISTAGG(DISTINCT region, ', '), '') AS regions,
        ...
FROM {{ ref('myschema.table_T') }}
GROUP BY userid
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you would like to know. How should we know what is the best query for you? You will need to show some sample data, the expected result and explain what is unclear to you.

Comment: Can you share the full query ?

Comment: Hi both, thanks for the feedback. I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the aggregates string reach the limit, you can't use the `LISTAGG` function. You could create a user-defined aggregate function instead :

```
create or replace function full_array_agg(g string, s string)
returns table (G string, S array)
language javascript
as $$
{
    processRow: function f(row, rowWriter, context){
        if( this.arr.indexOf(row.S) === -1 ) {
          this.arr.push(row.S)
        }
        this.group = row.G
        this.counter++;
    }
    , initialize: function(argumentInfo, context) {
        this.counter = 0;
        this.arr = [];
    }, finalize: function(rowWriter, context){
        rowWriter.writeRow({G:this.group, S: this.arr})
    }
}
$$;
```

You can use it like this :

```
select cities.g as userid, cities.s as cities
from mytable
    , table(full_array_agg(
        userid::string, 
        city) over(partition by userid)) cities;
```

Inspired from this answer :

- [String '(LISTAGG result)' is too long and would be truncated - How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71476770/4286884)