# Snowflake - ARRAY_AGG with LIMIT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, array-agg

We can use [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg) aggregate function to generate an array from data.

The goal is to find a way to limit the input to specific number of entries like `ARRAY_AGG(...) WITHIN GROUP(... LIMIT 3)` **without restructuring the main query**.

Sidenote: UDAF (User-Defined Aggregate Functions) are not available at the moment of writing.

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(grp TEXT, col TEXT) AS
SELECT * FROM VALUES 
  ('Grp1', 'A'),('Grp1', 'B'),('Grp1', 'C'),('Grp1', 'D'), ('Grp1', 'E'),
  ('Grp2', 'X'),('Grp2', 'Y'),('Grp2', 'Z'),('Grp2', 'V'),
  ('Grp3', 'M'),('Grp3', 'N'),('Grp3', 'M');
```

Output:

```
GRP ARR_LIMIT_3
Grp3    [   "M",   "M",   "N" ]
Grp2    [   "V",   "X",   "Y" ]
Grp1    [   "A",   "B",   "C" ]
```

Usage of `ARRAY_SLICE` is not an option if underlying `ARRAY_AGG` exceeds 16MB

```
SELECT grp, 
       ARRAY_SLICE(ARRAY_AGG(col), 1,3)) 
FROM big_table
JOIN ...
GROUP BY grp;
-- Result array of ARRAYAGG is too large
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to achieve similar effect by using [MIN_BY/MIN_MAX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/min_by) function:

> MIN_BY( <col_to_return>, <col_containing_mininum> [ , <maximum_number_of_values_to_return> ] )

```
SELECT grp,
       ARRAY_AGG(col) AS arr,
       MIN_BY(col, col, 3) AS arr_limit_3
FROM tab
GROUP BY grp;
```

Output:

| GRP | ARR | ARR_LIMIT_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Grp3 | [ "M", "N", "M" ] | [ "M", "M", "N" ] |
| Grp2 | [ "X", "Y", "Z", "V" ] | [ "V", "X", "Y" ] |
| Grp1 | [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] | [ "A", "B", "C" ] |

If the sorting is irrelevant then `MIN_BY(col, 'some_constant', 3)`.

---

`ARRAY_UNIQUE_AGG` or `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT ...)` is:

```
SELECT grp,
       ARRAY_UNIQUE_AGG(col) AS arr,
       ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT col) AS arr2,
       ARRAY_DISTINCT(MIN_BY(col, col, 3)) AS arr_distinct_limit_3
FROM tab
GROUP BY grp;
```

Output:

| GRP | ARR | ARR2 | ARR_DISTINCT_LIMIT_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grp3 | [ "M", "N" ] | [ "M", "N" ] | [ "M", "N" ] |
| Grp2 | [ "X", "Y", "Z", "V" ] | [ "X", "Y", "Z", "V" ] | [ "V", "X", "Y" ] |
| Grp1 | [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] | [ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" ] | [ "A", "B", "C" ] |

---

It is possible to handle `WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY <some_col> ASC/DESC)` too:

```
SELECT grp,
       -- ASC
       ARRAY_AGG(col) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY some_col),
       MIN_BY(col, some_col, 3),
       -- DESC
       ARRAY_AGG(col) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY some_col DESC),
       MAX_BY(col, some_col, 3)
FROM ...;
```

Comment: Is there a parenthesis issue in the last code block perhaps?